# Swift UiTable.reloadData only refreshing from seperate button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Storyboard Table View with a custom cell being fed data from an array, I need to be able to add times from a time picker and refresh the table.

Currently, I cannot seem to get it to refresh from the button click of the picker view. it will only refresh when calling reloadData from another UIButton. When reloadData is called from here it works instantly but no matter what I do I cannot get it to refresh from the picker button.

I am not purposefully using any other threads, the data is already in existence before this screen even loads.
I have tracked when each func is called and there is no difference between the sequence of events between the two options, the only difference is the manner in which they are called.

```
import UIKit
import FontAwesome_swift
import Foundation
class CreateScheduleViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var btnDone: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnAddTime: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btnGoBack: UIButton!
@IBInspectable var userIndex: Int = 0;
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
private let helper = Helpers();
private let colors = Colors();
private var timesList: [ScheduleItem] = [];

/// Returns the number of rows to draw in the table
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - tableView: the parent table view
///   - section: the section to create
/// - Returns: the number of rows
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //get the number of doses times for the user
    return timesList.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ScheduleCell", for: indexPath) as! CreateScheduleCell;
    if(timesList.count > 0){
        let time: String = helper.formatAs12Hour(timesList[indexPath.row].getDoseTime());
        cell.lblTimeDisplay?.text = time;
    }else{
        cell.lblTimeDisplay?.text = "No Time";
    }
    cell.imgClockIcon.image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .clockO, textColor: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40));
    cell.btnMoreOptions.setImage(UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .ellipsisH, textColor: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 20)), for: .normal);
    return cell;

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //setup add time button
    btnAddTime.setImage(UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .clockO, textColor: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)), for: .normal);
    btnAddTime.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -25, bottom: 0, right: 0);
    //setup the done button
    btnDone.setImage(UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .checkCircleO, textColor: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)), for: .normal);
    btnDone.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -25, bottom: 0, right: 0);
    getCurrentSchedule();
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func btnGoBack_clicked(_ sender: Any) {
}


@IBAction func btnAddTime_clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    showPicker();
}


@IBAction func btnDone_clicked(_ sender: Any) {
    self.myTableView.reloadData();

}

private func getCurrentSchedule(){
    if(CurrentUser.getMonitorDevices()[userIndex].getSchedule().count > 0){
        var schedules: [Schedule] = CurrentUser.getMonitorDevices()[userIndex].getSchedule();
        timesList.removeAll();
        for i in 0 ..< schedules.count{
            let item = ScheduleItem();
            item.setDoseTime(doseTime: schedules[i].getTime());
            item.setIsSelected(isSelected: false);
            timesList.append(item);
        }
    }
}

private func showPicker(){
    let message = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Choose a Time", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet);
    alert.isModalInPopover = true
    alert.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: "Please Choose a Time", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : colors.InstrumentBlue]), forKey: "attributedTitle");
    let timePicker = UIDatePicker();
    timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time;
    timePicker.locale = Locale.current;
    timePicker.timeZone = TimeZone.current;
    //Add the picker to the alert controller
    alert.view.addSubview(timePicker);
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        let newTime = timePicker.date;
        let StringTime: String = self.formatPickerTime(chosenTime: String(describing: newTime)as String!);
        if(self.doesDoseExist(time:StringTime)){
            //TODO display error
        }else{
            let item = ScheduleItem();
            item.setDoseTime(doseTime: StringTime);
            item.setIsSelected(isSelected: false);
            self.timesList.append(item);
            self.myTableView.reloadData();
        }
    })
    alert.addAction(okAction);
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil);
    alert.addAction(cancelAction);
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);
}

/// formats the time coming from the time picker to the curent TZ and in 24h format
///
/// - Parameter chosenTime: the time from the picker
/// - Returns: the formatted time
private func formatPickerTime(chosenTime: String)->String{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter();
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current;
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z";
    let dateFormattedTime: Date = dateFormatter.date(from: chosenTime)!;
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
    let stringFormattedTime: String = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFormattedTime);
    print(stringFormattedTime);
    return stringFormattedTime;
}

/// checks if a time being added already exists in the list
///
/// - Parameter time: the time chosen
/// - Returns: the boolean result
private func doesDoseExist(time: String)->Bool{
    var doseExists: Bool = false;
    for i in 0 ..< timesList.count{
        if(time == timesList[i].getDoseTime()){
            doseExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return doseExists;
}


private func sortList(){
    var times: [String] = [];
    var dates: [Date] = [];
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter();
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss";
    for item: ScheduleItem in timesList{
        dates.append(dateFormatter.date(from: item.getDoseTime())!);
    }
    let sortedDateArray = dates.sorted(by: {$0.compare($1) == .orderedDescending})

    }

private func showDoneButton(){
    if(timesList.count > 0){
        //if no times have been added: hide the button
        btnDone.isHidden = false;
    }else{
        btnDone.isHidden = true;
    }
}

}



class CreateScheduleCell: UITableViewCell{
@IBOutlet weak var btnMoreOptions: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var lblTimeDisplay: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imgClockIcon: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: Not related to the issue but remove **all** semicolons. They are redundant in Swift.

Comment: Pointing it out without providing useful info is also redundant.